# Run file NOT as administrator

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, admin

I'm trying to test a batch file that should test for administrator privileges, but I have the weird problem that I can't run it without administrator privileges.

```
net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorLevel% == 0 (
    rem do whatever...
```

Sure, I can just create another user account and run it from there, but that's a bit much effort just for one little test.

The script example above may not exactly be what I wanted because I need a general solution, for example to test if an installer can run without admin rights.

Is there an easier way? A command line argument for running something without administrator privileges maybe?

BTW, I disabled UAC if that makes any difference.

Comment: …and you figured that not providing the batch file or your method of running it was the best way to get a solution, did you?

Comment: Sounds like you have either disabled UAC or are logged in to the built-in Administrator account.  You can create a user account fairly quickly and easily using `net user testaccount password /add` and test your batch file using `runas /user:testaccount cmd`.

Comment: The script is     net session >nul 2>&1     \n     if %errorLevel% == 0 (     But I wanted a general solution also. For example to test if an installer can run without admin rights.

Comment: Yes, I disabled UAC, that's true. I'll try your commands in ~12 hours, @Harry Johnston.

Comment: @Compo Thank you for your change, that's exactly how I would word it.

Comment: Thank you, @HarryJohnston, that works, too. It's not really the solution I asked for, but it avoids the hassle of creating a new account through the system settings and switching accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "cmd.exe /c ....."
```

use `runas /showtrustlevels` to see the available levels

Comment: Be aware that this generates a non-standard token, one with [unusual properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970434/886887).  Probably not the best context for testing.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Thank you, I didn't saw it. I tried in windows 10 from the restricted console and while `whoami /all` reports group membership, it also reports the only active right is `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege`. File system operations and usual admin operations were restricted. Probably  (?) , for a *"little test"* as indicated it is enough.

Comment: I've now confirmed that the same issue occurs when using `runas` in Windows 10.  You can see it via `whoami /groups`, the last line is usually the mandatory label and if it says "High Mandatory Level" you still have some elevated rights -  specifically, you can interact with elevated GUI applications in ways that are normally forbidden to non-elevated processes.  I think that's it, though, and it probably isn't relevant to what the OP is doing.