# Can applications using IPC shared memory access each other's code?

Tags: c++, windows, api, process, ipc

I want to develop an application that takes data from a 3rd party application, processes it and send back result to the 3rd party app. It should basically be a black box for the 3rd party app, both communicating just via the apps's API's.

Now I need to know, how to make two separate applications communicate. I came across IPC technology and read about Shared Memory IPC and Message Passing IPC.

Since the former IPC makes the applications shared data in the same place, can the apps potentially see each other's code?

Which technology is the one to go? Are there more things to consider regarding app to app communication?

Thank you.

OS: Windows

Language: C++

Network access: offline

Comment: Not directly related, but more fine tuning information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3795911/1460794).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they can't access each other's code. The only memory that's shared are the specific pages that were allocated using the shared memory system calls. Other parts of memory are unrelated.